# ng build --prod error after removing the bootstrap

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, node-modules, terser

I am using angular11 and after removing the bootstrap from my project it gives below error when run command ng build --prod
Earlier it is working fine. i tried to update core and terser depenadicies but no luck. please help.

```
Error: scripts.d4d60eb3a58ff1e99223.js from Terser
```

Unexpected character '@' [scripts.d4d60eb3a58ff1e99223.js:3,0]
at js_error (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:550:11)
at parse_error (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:686:9)
at Object.next_token [as input] (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1119:9)
at peek (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1254:56)
at next (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1259:24)
at parse (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1248:15)
at minify (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:27665:42)
at minify (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:162:24)
at Object.transform (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\minify.js:175:10)
at execFunction (D:\Projects\PorticoWebApp\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:145:17)

Comment: Just delete node_modules folder, run `npm install` in your project folder and try again.

Comment: @smithnblack i tried this but no luck. same error.

Comment: Solved now! I'm in Angular 11, in my case it gave the same error, but it was my mistake: in angular.json I didn't import the styles and scripts correctly ("styles": [], "scripts": []),always check if the imports of your project are correct, because if it is wrong, this same error will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-install package after that delete Terser package in node-modules. If doesn't solve the problem, can you type package version.